# Version Control Systems, lock files on read

Tags: file, svn, version-control, locking, collaboration

I'm in a company which demands simultaneously collaboration on a web application, to avoid any conflict during development our CEO suggests the use of SVN version control system so each user can lock the file when they're working on it. 
SVN does support locking files for each user but the problem is we need to lock the file on reading, SVN as I know to make you check for any updates every time you want to see the locking status on files. What we need is to not letting other users even open/read the files that have been locked! does SVN have such a feature?! or is there any other technologies like google drive to achieve such a mechanism?
Thank you all.

Comment: Locks affect Write capabilities only and do not affect Read.

Comment: is there any other tech,system(like sharepoint) to make us capable of lock on read?!

Comment: BTW, if you put `svn:needs-lock` property, SVN will prompt user to lock the file before he could start modifying it locally. Read about locking in SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.locking.html

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments, but what we want is to prevent other users from even opening files when they're locked. point is  we want team members not to waste their time on a file that has been locked by someone else and they only realize it when they want to commit that change. I hope make my point here.